# SwiftUI: How to show/edit an int from CoreData without being in a List?

Tags: core-data, swiftui

self-learning beginner here. I am trying to show an Int from Core Data in a VStack in ContentView, not in a List. But literally all the tutorials I can find about Core Data (tracking Books, Movies, Orders, Students) are using a List to show an array containing an Int. Nothing on showing an Int by itself.

Xcode can build countnum.countnum +=1 with no problem. Seems to me it is reading it fine. But once I try to show it, it just doesn’t work.  I’m wrecking my brain here.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: []) var countnum: FetchedResults<CountNum>
    
    var body: some View {
//        let countnum = CountNum(context: moc)
        VStack{
            Text("+")
                .padding()
                .onTapGesture (count: 2){
                    let countnum = CountNum(context: moc)
                    countnum.countnum += 1
                }
            Text("\(countnum)") //No exact matches in call to instance method 'appendInterpolation'
        }
        
        
    }
}
```

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Look at the sheet [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69330564/use-the-same-view-for-adding-and-editing-coredata-objects/69330873#69330873)

Comment: @loremipsum Thank you for the answer.  But I gotta be honest. The code there looks way above my current (close to non-exist) ability to read code.

Comment: @loremipsum If I try my best to understand it. The .sheet has an action $vm.newItem .  Are you say I need to add an item in my entity?

Comment: No the `sheet(item)` is triggered when `@Published var newItem: Item? = nil` is `!=` to `nil`. The `Button` with `vm.addItem(moc: viewContext)` creates a new object then puts the object on the `newItem`. The sheet then opens with the new object. `Item` is just the sample entity that comes with a new Xcode project. You can take that code and paste it in one so you can see how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`....all the tutorials ... show an array containing an Int.` Yes, that's because CoreData
can contain many "objects". You get an array of your `CountNum` objects when
you do your `.....var countnum: FetchedResults<CountNum>`. So you need to decide which `CountNum` you want to
use. For example, if you want to use the first one, then:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: []) var countnum: FetchedResults<CountNum>
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if let firstItem = countnum.first {
                Text("+")
                    .padding()
                    .onTapGesture(count: 2) {
                        firstItem.countnum += 1
                        do {
                            try moc.save()
                        } catch {
                            print(error)
                        }
                    }
                Text("\(firstItem.countnum)").foregroundColor(.green)
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

EDIT-1: adding new CountNum to CoreData example code in the `add` button.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: []) var countnum: FetchedResults<CountNum>
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {add()}) { Text("add new CountNum").foregroundColor(.green) }
        .padding(.top, 50)
        List {
            ForEach(countnum) { item in
                HStack {
                    Text("++")
                        .onTapGesture(count: 2) { increment(item) }
                    Text("\(item.countnum)").foregroundColor(.blue)
                    Text("delete").foregroundColor(.red)
                        .onTapGesture { delete(item: item) }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func increment(_ item: CountNum) {
        item.countnum += 1
        save()
    }
    
    func add() {
        let countnum = CountNum(context: moc)
        countnum.countnum = 0
        save()
    }
    
    func delete(item: CountNum) {
        moc.delete(item)
        save()
    }
    
    func save() {
        do { try moc.save() } catch { print(error) }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is exaclty what I had in mind.  Just one single int.  The code works when I run it. But for some reason there is nothing shown but a blank sheet on the simulator.  Any quick thought?
https://imgur.com/a/eKiw60P

Comment: yes, it's probably because you do not have any data in your CoreData. You can easily add some using 
 the EDIT-1 code in my updated answer. If this answer your questions, please consider marking my 
 answer as correct, thank you.